# count variables if they exist

Tags: php

Below is a small part of my raw json file, if a user is in game the game field appears in the json if there not in game the json removes the game field. I am trying to count how many users are in game by counting the game fields

> Raw json

```
"members": [
    {
      "username": "Squadman",
      "game": {
        "name": "World of Warcraft"
      },
    }
   ]
```

what i have working on one part is

```
$count = count($result['members']);
```

and i echo it out like this

```
<strong><?php echo $count; ?></strong>
```

but that just counts members I want to count the members only in game i tried

```
 $countingame = count($result['members']['game]);
```

But get no result

Comment: are you calling json_decode with $assoc true or false or omitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this and this should work:

JSON code:

```
{
    "members": [
        {
            "username": "Squadman",
            "game": {
                "name": "World of Warcraft"
            }
        },
        {
            "username": "Bob",
            "game": {
                "name": "Battlefield"
            }
        },
        {
            "username": "Jane"
        }
    ]
}
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('https://example.com/file.json');

$decodedJson = json_decode($json, true);
$array = $decodedJson['members'];

$count = 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($value['game']['name']) && $value['game']['name'] != '') {
        $count++;
    }
}

echo $count;

?>
```

Comment: that worked part of the way.. if a user is in game it shows but for the users not in game it show and error of undefined. as i stated in my question if the user is ingame the json adds the field game but if there not json removes the game so for those not in a game it gives the error

Comment: Replace if condition with `if( isset($value['game']['name']) && $value['game']['name'] != '')`

Comment: @JaiprakashKhowal Was about to add that from the beginning but thought, "meh, this will do". Lol thanks though. I edited the original answer.

Comment: Can we not use if (!empty($value['game']['name'])) { $count++; } http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/189d93b7317887d286fb18118fd00f45c8df7ebd

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen Yes, there are a bunch of ways to check if one does not exist. You can use `!isset`, `null`, `is_null`, `empty`, etc... I'll leave it up to the OP to decide.

Answer (score 1):

To count members in games, you need to check for the existence of the 'game' key in the members array that you get from json_decode. You can do that with isset.

```
$result = json_decode($result, true);

$count = count($result['members']);
for ($countingame = $i = 0; $i++; $i < $count)
    $countingame += isset($result['members'][$i]['game']) ? 1 : 0;

echo "$count members in $countingame games";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

> $countingame = count($result['members'][0]['game]);

As members is an array

Comment: it gives me 2 errors Notice: Undefined index: game in and Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Comment: Convert your json to array/object first. Example: $result = json_decode($json, true); for array